# When is the inverse image of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis

I learned that if $f:X\to Y$ where $X,Y$ are metric spaces and $f$ is uniformly continuous then the image of a Cauchy sequence is also Cauchy. I am wondering under what condition is the reverse condition true. Is it always true? Any counter-examples to this end will be much appreciated.

For starters, I think that we could ask $f$ to be a bijective map. If $Y$ is complete and $f^{-1}$ is a continuous map then a Cauchy sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $Y$ will be convergent and thus $f^{-1}(y_n)$ will be convergent in $X$ and thus Cauchy. But maybe this is a strong condition.

Comment: Completeness of $Y$ required? I suppose $f$ being bijective and continuous is sufficient.

Comment: Bijectivity is strong but necessary. Otherwise, if you have $x_1,x_2 \in X, x_1 \neq x_2$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$, then the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ is not Cauchy, but the image sequence is.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis of $f$ injective is reasonable, since otherwise, in the case that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$, the sequence
$$x_n=\begin{cases}x_0 & n \text{ even}\\x_1 & n \text{ odd}\\\end{cases}$$
is not Cauchy although $f(x_n)$ is (because is constant).

To assume completeness seems excessive, since this turns Cauchy sequences into the same as convergent sequences. Even completeness of just one space seems like too much. It would be interesting to analyze the case in which neither space is complete before trying that.

Of course, injectivity and uniform continuity of $g\colon f(X) \rightarrow X$, where 
$$g(y)=x \iff f(x)=y$$
would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

This is open to corrections.

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $Y$. Then for $\varepsilon>0\:\exists \: N\in\mathbb{N}\::\: |y_n-y_m|<\varepsilon$. Assume $f$ is bijective and continuous.

So  $ \text{for each }\:n \:\exists\: x_n\in X \::\: f(x_n)=y_n$. For $n>N$, consider the neighbourhood $B(y_n,\varepsilon)$. $f^{-1}\left(B(y_n,\varepsilon)\right)\supseteq B(f^{-1}(y_n),\delta)$. Choosing $\delta =\varepsilon$ should do.